# Sql Query - Limiting query results

Tags: sql, mysql

I am quite certain we cannot use the LIMIT clause for what I want to do - so wanted to find if there are any other ways we can accomplish this.

I have a table which captures which user visited which store. Every time a user visits a store, a row is inserted into this table.

Some of the fields are

- shopping_id (primary key)
- store_id
- user_id

Now what I want is - for a given set of stores, find the top 5 users who have visited the store max number of times.

I can do this 1 store at a time as:

`select store_id,user_id,count(1) as visits 
from shopping 
where store_id = 60
group by user_id,store_id 
order by visits desc Limit 5`

This will give me the 5 users who have visited store_id=60 the max times

What I want to do is provide a list of 10 store_ids and for each store fetch the 5 users who have visited that store max times

`select store_id,user_id,count(1) as visits 
from shopping 
where store_id in  (60,61,62,63,64,65,66)
group by user_id,store_id 
order by visits desc Limit 5`

This will not work as the Limit at the end will return only 5 rows rather than 5 rows for each store.

Any ideas on how I can achieve this. I can always write a loop and pass 1 store at a time but wanted to know if there is a better way

Comment: MySQL doesn't have analytic functions - ROW_NUMBER, RANK, DENSE_RANK - that you would normally use to solve situations like these.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using two user variable and counting the same consecutive store_id, you can replace `<= 5` with whatever limit you want

```
SELECT a.*
FROM (
 SELECT store_id, user_id, count(1) as visits 
 FROM shopping
 WHERE store_id IN (60,61,62,63,64,65,66)
 GROUP BY store_id, user_id
 ORDER BY store_id, visits desc, user_id
) a,
(SELECT @prev:=-1, @count:=1) b
WHERE
 CASE WHEN @prev<>a.store_id THEN
   CASE WHEN @prev:=a.store_id THEN
    @count:=1
   END
 ELSE
   @count:=@count+1
 END <= 5
```

**Edit as requested some explanation :**

The first subquery (a) is the one that group and order the data so you will have data like:

```
store_id | user_id | visits
---------+---------+-------
 60           1       5
 60           2       3
 60           3       1
 61           2       4
 61           3       2
```

the second subquery (b) init the user variable `@prev` with -1 and  `@count` with 1

then we choose all data from the subquery (a) verifying the condition in the `case`.

- verify that the previous store_id (`@prev`) we have seen is different from the current            store_id.
  Since the first `@prev` is equal to -1 there is nothing that match the current store_id so the condition `<>` is true we enter then is the second case who just serve to change the value `@prev` with the current store_id. This is the trick so i can change the two user variable `@count` and `@prev` in the same condition.
- if the previous store_id is equal to `@prev` just increment the `@count` variable.
- we check that the count is within the value we want so the `<= 5`

So with our test data the:

```
step | @prev | @count | store_id | user_id | visits
-----+-------+--------+----------+---------+-------
  0      -1      1    
  1      60      1        60          1        5 
  2      60      2        60          2        3
  3      60      3        60          3        1
  4      61      1        61          2        4
  5      61      2        61          3        2
```

Comment: Hey Patrick - I have never seen a query like this :) but it works perfectly. I tried with my test data and it gives the exact results I was looking for. I'll have to now study what this query is doing. Thank you so much

Comment: Hey Patrick - I have never seen a query like this :)
Please explain the code. So that we can learn from it.
I will be thankful.

Comment: @Gubloo, @RAHUL PRASAD added some explanation

Comment: Thankyou patrick - that explanation was very clear and helpful. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Major concern over here is number of times you query a database.
If you query multiple times from your script. Its simply wastage of resources and must be avoided.
That is you must NOT run a loop to run the SQL multiple times by incrementing certain value. In your case 60 to 61 and so on.

Solution 1:
Create a view
Here is the solution

```
CREATE VIEW myView AS
select store_id,user_id,count(1) as visits 
from shopping 
where store_id = 60
group by user_id,store_id 
order by visits desc Limit 5
UNION
select store_id,user_id,count(1) as visits 
from shopping 
where store_id = 61
group by user_id,store_id 
order by visits desc Limit 5
UNION
select store_id,user_id,count(1) as visits 
from shopping 
where store_id = 62
group by user_id,store_id
order by visits desc Limit 5
```

Now use

```
SELECT * from MyView
```

This is limited because you cant make it dynamic.
What if you need 60 to 100 instead of 60 to 66.

Solution 2:
Use Procedure.
I wont go into how to write a procedure cuz its late night and I got to sleep. :)
Well, procedure must accept two values 1st inital number (60) and 2nd Count (6)
Inside the procedure create a temporary table (cursor) to store data then run a loop from initial number till count times
In your case from 60 to 66
Inside the loop write desired script Replacing 60 with a looping variable.

```
select store_id,user_id,count(1) as visits 
from shopping 
where store_id = 60
group by user_id,store_id 
order by visits desc Limit 5
```

And append the result in the temporary table (cursor).

Hope this will solve your problem.
Sorry I couldn't give you the code. If you still need it plz send me a message. I will give it to you when I wake up next morning.

Answer (score 1):

UNION may be what you are looking for.

```
-- fist store
(select store_id,user_id,count(1) as visits 
from shopping 
where store_id = 60
group by user_id,store_id 
order by visits desc Limit 5)
UNION ALL
-- second store
(select store_id,user_id,count(1) as visits 
from shopping 
where store_id = 61
group by user_id,store_id 
order by visits desc Limit 5)
...
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html

Answer (score 1):

If you will not save data about when a user visited a store or something like this, you could simply update the table each time a user visits a store instead of appending a new row.

Something like this:

```
INSERT INTO `user_store` (`user_id`, `store_id`, `visits`) VALUES ('USER', 'SHOP', 1)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `visits` = `visits` + 1
```

But I think this would not work, because neither user_id nor store_id are unique. You have to add a unique primary key like this: user#store or something else.

Another opinion would be to save this data (how often a user was in a store) in a separate table containing of ID, user_id, store_id, visits and increment visits everytime you also add a new row to you existing table.

To get the Top5 you can then use:

```
SELECT `visits`, `user_id` FROM `user_store_times` WHERE `store_id`=10 ORDER BY `visits` DESC LIMIT 5
```

Comment: Thanx for 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `visits` = `visits` + 1
thing.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to issue 10 separate queries, one for each store. If you use parameterized queries (e.g. using [PDO in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php)) this will be pretty fast since the query will be part-compiled.

If this still proves to be too resource-intensive, then another solution would be to cache the results in the store table - i.e. add a field that lists the top 5 users for each store as a simple comma-separated list. It does mean your database would not be 100% normalised but that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Hmmm thats an interesting idea - so you are suggesting - everytime a user visits a store - at that time itself do a check and update the top 5 users column. I thought of that approach but then decided against it thinking why to store data permanently that can be retrieved with some simple SQL

Comment: @Gubloo: I meant that you would run a script (as a cron job, or for the first user who visits after midnight, say) which would do the updates. What you said may still be too resource-intensive. You're right though - if you can get the data with a simple query then that's certainly better, but it looks like your accepted answer is pretty far from simple ;)

Comment: :) - well although that query looks complex - I'm not sure how resource intensive it is - but atleast its a simple way of getting the results on the fly.