# How to change this SQL so that I can get one post from each author?

Tags: sql, mysql, inner-join

In the sql below I have the last 5 posts. But sometimes these posts are from the same author. I want to select the last 5 but just one per author.

```
SELECT `e` . * , 
       `f`.`title` AS `feedTitle` , 
       `f`.`url` AS `feedUrl` , 
       `a`.`id` AS `authorId` , 
       `a`.`name` AS `authorName` , 
       `a`.`about` AS `authorAbout`
FROM `feed_entries` AS `e`
INNER JOIN `feeds` AS `f` ON e.feed_id = f.id
INNER JOIN `entries_categories` AS `ec` ON ec.entry_id = e.id
INNER JOIN `categories` AS `c` ON ec.category_id = c.id
INNER JOIN `authors` AS `a` ON e.author_id = a.id
GROUP BY `e`.`id`
ORDER BY `e`.`date` DESC
LIMIT 5
```

**EDITED**

I've ended up with it:

```
SELECT a.id, e.date, e.title, a.name
FROM feed_entries e, authors a 
WHERE e.author_id =a.id 
ORDER BY e.date DESC 
LIMIT 5
```

In this query, how can I get just one post for each author?

Comment: What determines the post that you want to select? The latest one? A random one?

Comment: Actually this SQL list all posts ordened by date. But sometimes I get two posts from just one author. I need to change so that I get DISTINCT a.id (author ID)

Comment: @Keyne: so replace your existing SELECT clause with `SELECT DISTINCT a.id (author ID)`... . On the other hand, if you also want to include details from a single post for each author, please can you answer Daniel's question?

Comment: @Mark I've tried to select distinct a.id but nothing. I will try again, maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: Distinct is what you want here.

Comment: @Chris Distinct is for an entire row. Dont't work for a single column. Right?

Comment: @Kenye: see http://www.mysqlfaqs.net/mysql-faqs/SQL-Statements/Select-Statement/How-does-DISTINCT-work-in-MySQL Good example there.  You want distinct author set at which point you can possibly perform an outer query.  Im not expert though.

Comment: @Chirs Yes, but I couldn't get it to work with distinct. Even with group by joining these two tables and ordering by date. Until now the only solution is with subqueries. In theory I agree with you, but is not what's happening. If you could provide tested examples based on this scenario I'd apriciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got the anwser here: [DISTINCT a column in a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2410984/distinct-a-column-in-a-database)

I've did some modifications and works fine.

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT `e` . * , 
       `f`.`title` AS `feedTitle` , 
       `f`.`url` AS `feedUrl` , 
       `a`.`id` AS `authorId` , 
       `a`.`name` AS `authorName` , 
       `a`.`about` AS `authorAbout`
FROM `feed_entries` AS `e`
INNER JOIN `feeds` AS `f` ON e.feed_id = f.id
INNER JOIN `entries_categories` AS `ec` ON ec.entry_id = e.id
INNER JOIN `categories` AS `c` ON ec.category_id = c.id
INNER JOIN `authors` AS `a` ON e.author_id = a.id
GROUP BY `e`.`id`
ORDER BY `e`.`date` DESC
) t GROUP BY author_id ORDER BY date DESC 
LIMIT 5
```

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
select a.id, a.name, e.date, e.titulo
  from feed_entries e
 inner join authors a
    on e.author_id = a.id
    -- Get the most recent feed_entry
   and e.date = (select max(e1.date) from feed_entries e1 where e1.author_id = a.id)
 order by e.date desc
```

I haven't tested that but it could work.

Comment: Seems to work with the first results, but after 10 or more the date is not ordened correctly and after 20 I see duplicated entries. Very strange! Maybe I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something along these lines (not tested yet):

```
SELECT `e` . * , `f`.`title` AS `feedTitle` , `f`.`url` AS `feedUrl` , `a`.`id` AS `authorId` , `a`.`name` AS `authorName` , `a`.`about` AS `authorAbout`
FROM `feed_entries` AS `e`
INNER JOIN `feeds` AS `f` ON e.feed_id = f.id
INNER JOIN `entries_categories` AS `ec` ON ec.entry_id = e.id
INNER JOIN `categories` AS `c` ON ec.category_id = c.id
INNER JOIN `authors` AS `a` ON e.author_id = a.id
INNER JOIN ( SELECT TOP 1 entry_id, author_id 
             FROM feed_entries 
             GROUP BY author_id 
             ORDER BY date DESC) as top_article
ON (a.id = top_article.author_id)
GROUP BY `e`.`id`
ORDER BY `e`.`date` DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Comment: I fixed the subquery; try it again

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Now the query works, but I still receiving duplicated posts from the same author. Other consideration is, I cant get the latest posts by ID, I need by date.

Comment: I modified the subquery to order by date.  I'm not sure why you're getting duplicated posts however.